# How to build mongodb from source version 2.2.7 windows

Tags: windows, mongodb

I want to build MongDB from source, in order to increase the BSON Size limit.

I am on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should not be using MongoDB 2.2. That is a very, very old version of MongoDB that is no longer maintained. It reached end of life 2 years ago (February 2014).
2. You should consider why you want to increase the BSON size limit. Generally speaking if you are getting anywhere close to 16MB you should consider breaking your schema down into smaller documents. If you're storing large binary data, you should use GridFS.

Comment: i cant use grid fs. i want the data to be searchable